# sendmail with input file not working

Tags: sendmail

I cannot make `sendmail` work with an input file.

This works fine:

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v my@email.com
```

However, if I have file:

```
To: mymail@gmail.com
Subject: sendmail test two
From: me@myserver.com

And here goes the e-mail body, test test test
and new line
```

And then I do `sendmail -t < mail.txt` the program hangs. In verbose mode it just says:

```
250 2.1.5 <mymail@gmail.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
```

I end it with a `dot`, nothing happens. It just stays.
If I do nothing, after a while it says:

```
myserver.com: Name server timeout
mymail@gmail.com... Deferred: Name server: [127.0.0.1]: host 
name lookup failure
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add two return to line after the dot.

Comment: same situation...